# Layout does not Appear Right in iPad/Safari

Tags: html, css, ipad, safari

I've been building the website http://orion.viperdmc.com. The layout seems to work fine on all browsers except for Safari running on the iPad.

On that browser, if I resize the page so that the large image at the top fits the iPad display, the content below appears left-aligned instead of center.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think you can fix it by matching the width of the first container in the mark-up to the image (`#feature-image-inner`):

So add a class of `.first` to the first `.container` in your markup:

```
<div class="container first">
```

Then target it with the CSS below.

```
.container.first{
    width: 1280px;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Doesn't that change the width of my content? I don't want to change the width of the other content.

Comment: You can mimic the issue on your desktop. Shrink the window until only the text is showing with no margins. You can still scroll right to see the rest of the image and the text appears to be left aligned i.e. the same layout as on the ipad but you have to scroll to see it. At the moment the minimum width of your page without scroll bars appearing will be `1280px` because you've set that on `#feature-image-inner`. So you need to change just the first `.container` to match that width so it doesn't shrink. The inner content won't grow. It will look the same and stay centred. Try it & let me know.

Comment: You're exactly right. That fixed it and it still looks right on the PC. I'm still a little confused by that, however. Why does fixing only the first contain make it right for the containers that follow?

Comment: Actually, nevermind. Looks like I was missing a closing `</div>` tag so that the entire other content was enclosed within that first container. So it works because there is an outer container, which was unintended. I'll need to rework that a bit. Thanks!